# Рандомные значения из массива

Tags: массивы, php

Как выводить постоянно рандомные значения? **array_rand не помог**, так как не умеет работать с такими массивами:

```
$win_game_array = array(
 'Premium Minecraft' => '#127a0c',
 'CS: Global Offensive' => '#181cad',
 'Watch Dogs' => '#776b35',
 '"Секрет"' => '#e63e3e',
 'Steam random key' => '#bf58b9',
 'Battlefield 4' => '#a7911a',
 'Dayz Standalone' => '#3f988f',
 'ArmA 2' => '#d2ff00'
);

foreach($win_game_array as $key => $value) {
 echo '<div class="list_li"><span style="color: '.$value.'">'.$key.'</span></div>';
}
```

Comment: Оффтоп: @ModaL, я Вас помню ещё по 2012 году. Я не вижу прогресса. Почему?

`$win_game_array` вместо `$winGames` или же `$games`, вопрос [вида](http://goo.gl/A81RbK). Не подумайте, что я с каким-то претензиями, боже упаси. Просто есть у меня "дьявольская" привычка анализировать людей. Обычно за 3 года разработки люди матереют - больше отдают, нежели потребляют. [Тезаурус](http://goo.gl/2WN6i4) к этому времени пересекает [максимальную точку экстремума](http://images.myshared.ru/5/381344/slide_21.jpg)

Comment: @romeo, открытка @Роман Ракзин и @eprivalov1

Comment: @romeo, прогресс есть, правда. На счёт переменных понял, $winGames и правда лучше :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> array_rand не помог, так как не умеет работать с такими массивами:

шта?

```
<?php

$win_game_array = array(
 'Premium Minecraft' => '#127a0c',
 'CS: Global Offensive' => '#181cad',
 'Watch Dogs' => '#776b35',
 '"Секрет"' => '#e63e3e',
 'Steam random key' => '#bf58b9',
 'Battlefield 4' => '#a7911a',
 'Dayz Standalone' => '#3f988f',
 'ArmA 2' => '#d2ff00'
);

var_dump(array_rand($win_game_array));
```

Возвращает, как и ожидалось, рандомный ключ:

```
etki@vmint:~ > php t.php 
string(15) "Dayz Standalone"
etki@vmint:~ > php t.php 
string(17) "Premium Minecraft"
```

если вам нужно значение - берите его по ключу:

```
$randomKey = array_rand($win_game_array);
$randomValue = $win_game_array[$randomKey];
```